# How to generate SSL only for subdomain without add domain?

Tags: ssl-certificate, cloudflare

I am pretty new with the domain configuration part. I want to know that can I generate SSL only for my subdomain I didn't want to add the root domain with CLOUDFLARE because my root domain already has SSL certificate. Is it possible to do that? I have purchased my domain from the GODADDY. I will add the generated SSL certificate to IIS.

Please help me out !!

Edit: I don't want to add my root domain to CLOUDFLARE because if I will do it I have to change my NAMESERVER for the same and my root domain already has SSL.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is the [CNAME setup on Cloudflare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/360020348832-Understanding-a-CNAME-Setup). This is the alternative method of Name Server setup. **However, this setup requires a Business plan**. With CNAME setup, you can have just a certain subdomains to be used with Cloudflare. With proxy turned on the subdomain, you'd get the usual Universal SSL certification from Cloudflare.